# PHP Creating a formula from mysql db values and db stored math operator

Tags: plugins, php, functions, mysql

I am trying to use variables stored in a DB and  math operator (e.g. * + - /) to allow users to build formulas e.g. (Night Shift Hours*Night Shift Time Rate)*0.2

The formula string is build from separately stored values in the DB e.g. Night Shift Hours,base1_operator (* in this case) Night Shift Time Rate, base2_operator (* in this case too), payout_multiplier

(Night Shift Hours*Night Shift Time Rate)*0.2

How do I build a PHP formulae to actually use the DB values and produce a value amount (float)?

```
    global $post; 
    global $wpdb;
    global $post_type;
       
    // Get the current post_id
    $pid = ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : '' );       
    $pid = $post->ID;
    
    $pid2 = $_REQUEST['action'];
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'original_co', $pid2);   
    
    $company = get_post_meta($post_id, 'original_co',true);
    $component = get_post_meta($post_id, 'component',true);
    $component_inputtype = get_post_meta($post_id, 'component_inputtype',true);     
    $payout_amount = get_post_meta($post_id, 'payout_amount',true);
    $invoice_amount = get_post_meta($post_id, 'invoice_amount',true);
    $payout_operator = get_post_meta($post_id, 'payout_operator',true);
    $invoice_operator = get_post_meta($post_id, 'invoice_operator',true);       

    $base1_payout = get_post_meta($post_id, 'base1_payout',true);
    $base2_payout = get_post_meta($post_id, 'base2_payout',true);
    $base1_operator = get_post_meta($post_id, 'base1_operator',true);
    $base2_operator = get_post_meta($post_id, 'base2_operator',true);
    $payout_multiplier = get_post_meta($post_id, 'payout_multiplier',true);
    
    $base1_invoice = get_post_meta($post_id, 'base1_invoice',true);
    $base2_invoice = get_post_meta($post_id, 'base2_invoice',true);
    $invoice1_operator = get_post_meta($post_id, 'invoice1_operator',true);
    $invoice2_operator = get_post_meta($post_id, 'invoice2_operator',true);     
    $invoice_multiplier = get_post_meta($post_id, 'invoice_multiplier',true);
    
    $uid = $component.'_'.$pid2;
    $payout_formula = '('.$base1_payout.''.$base1_operator.''.$base2_payout.')'.$base2_operator.''.$payout_multiplier;  
    $invoice_formula = '('.$base1_invoice.''.$invoice1_operator.''.$base2_invoice.')'.$invoice2_operator.''.$invoice_multiplier;    
    
    
    if(strpos($component_inputtype, 'Amount') !== false) {
        
            $payout_formula = $payout_amount.''.$payout_operator.''.$payout_multiplier;
            $invoice_formula = $invoice_amount.''.$invoice_operator.''.$invoice_multiplier;
            //$payout_amount = $payout_amount,$payout_operator,$payout_multiplier;
            //echo $payout_amount;
            //exit:
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code. Otherwise your question is too vague to get a useful answer.

Comment: ok edited to include code.... i am trying to calculate $payout_amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i managed to get it to work with this

```
        $amount1 = $invoice_amount;
    $operator = $invoice_operator;
    $amount2 = $invoice_multiplier;
    $rvalue = mcalc ($amount1,$operator,$amount2);
    
    

    function mcalc ($amount1,$operator,$amount2) {
    
        if($operator=="+")
            $result=$amount1+$amount2;
        else if($operator=="-")
            $result=$amount1-$amount2;
        else if($operator=="x")
            $result=$amount1*$amount2;
        else if($operator=="/")
            $result=$amount1/$amount2;

        return $result;
    
    }
    
    echo $rvalue;
```